# Calculate Grid Position

Tags: math

I'm trying to figure out a way to calculate the positions in the grid like I have below.  I know the row, column, totalColumns, totalRows. For example, given column = 2, row = 0, totalColumns = 4, totalRows = 3, the position is B (11)

```
           Cols
       +   +   +   +   +
       | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 
    +--+---|---|---|---|---
     0 | 9 | A | B | C |
    +--+---|---|---|---|---  Rows
     1 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |   
    +--+---|---|---|---|---
     2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 
    +--+---|---|---|---|---
```

Comment: This has a homework-y look about it, so I'll just say this: Can you work out the number in the first column of a row, given its row number?

Comment: What is the question exactly? Are you asking how to number the cells in the grid sequentially going left-to-right bottom-to-top?

Comment: Please add an example, like `Row=2` and `Column=0` : `Result = ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah,, well, i guess you have better thinks to do than school ;))

```
 hex(tr*tc-r*tc-tc+c+1)
```